# how to find out with python on ubuntu if MySQL is running?

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, subprocess

On Ubuntu this command line:

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

if MySQL is running returns something like that:

```
tcp  0  0 localhost:mysql  *:*  LISTEN  6732/mysqld
```

and nothing if it's not.

I'm using subprocess to find out from inside the python code if MySQL is up by looking for a "LISTEN" in what that netstat returns, doing that:

```
import subprocess

msqlr = subprocess.Popen(["sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
msqlrLines = msqlr.split("\n")
vals = msqlrLines[0].split()
print "vals[0] : %s" % vals[0]
if vals[0][-2] == "LISTEN":
    print "OK - MySQL is running."
else:
    print "Not OK - MySQL is not running."
```

When I run this it returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When in the same subprocess.Popen... I use a one word argument (let's say "df") – it works OK. If the argument is more that one word (i.e. "df -h /" or, like here "sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql") – I'm getting this "No such file or directory" error.

And related question (#2), when I'm running this command in a command line — sometimes it asks for a root password. How do I pass a password from a python script?

Comment: Give the full path to netstat or add shell=True to the subprocess call.  The former being the preferred method.

Comment: @sberry: where exactly do I insert "shell=True"?

Comment: Also, you need `"sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql".split()`, not `[""sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql"]`

Comment: Would you be open to using just os?  import os; os.system("sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql")

Comment: @eudis-duran: how do I capture the output with os.system call? It returns 0 meaning there were no errors I suppose, but I need a string – the output of that command not just on the screen, but in a variable to work further with it.

Comment: @earlyadopter Well, the spec for os.system says that we can only get the return/exit status of the call.  You can work some shell logic into the above command, so that we fail (thus return >= 1) or pass ( == 0) based on whether grep returned any results or not.  Hope that was helpful.

Comment: what does `initctl status mysql` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something line this.

```
import subprocess
import string

msqlr = subprocess.Popen("sudo /usr/sbin/netstat -al".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
grep = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/grep", "mysql"], stdin=msqlr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
msqlrLines = grep.read().split("\n")
vals = map(string.strip, msqlrLines[0].split())
print vals
if vals[-1] in ("LISTENING", "LISTEN"):
    print "OK - MySQL is running."
else:
    print "Not OK - MySQL is not running."
```

**OUTPUT** on my machine:

```
['tcp4', '0', '0', '*.mysql', '*.*', 'LISTEN']
OK - MySQL is running.
```

The idea here is you do the normal netstat, and collect all of the data.  Then use the stdout from that subproc as the stdin for the next subproc and do your grep there.

Here is an example running on ubuntu 12.04

```
import subprocess
import string

msqlr = subprocess.Popen("sudo /bin/netstat -al".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
grep = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/grep", "mysql"], stdin=msqlr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
msqlrLines = grep.read().split("\n")
vals = map(string.strip, msqlrLines[0].split())
print vals
if len(vals) and vals[-1] in ("LISTENING", "LISTEN"):
    print "OK - MySQL is running."
else:
    print "Not OK - MySQL is not running."
```

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you running? mine is 12.10 inside a vistualbox on a mac

Comment: Well, this is on OSX.  Added an example that works on ubuntu.

Comment: yes, your code works! :) but there was a second question: how do I enter password from a python script instead of being asked to do that interactively?

Comment: never mind — already found an answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Answer (score 0):

Why not just see if you can connect in python:

```
try:

    con = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'user', 
        'password', 'testdb')

except _mysql.Error, e:

print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
sys.exit(1)
```